# Function to access element of struct in vector like a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I have a vector of structs:

```
struct vec_record {
unsigned int term;
unsigned int coef;
};
vector<vec_record> data;
```

And for some reason a want to make some operations on only one of the struct elements and then the same operations on the other but I want it to be seperate, so I have function:

```
void change(vector<unsigned int> &val) {
//some changes on data
}
```

It will perfectly work if I will have two vectors:

```
vector<unsigned int> term;
vector<unsigned int> coef;
change(term);
change(coef);
```

But I would like to be able to do it like this:

```
vector<vec_record> data;
change(data.term);    //not valid
change(data.coef);    //not valid
```

Is there a way to get this functionality?
Maybe using functional from C++11?

Comment: What you need is a projection – try [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/)'s `boost::adaptors::transform` and modify `change` to take a range instead of a `vector<>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointers-to-members are your solution in plain C++ :

```
void change(vector<vec_record> &data, unsigned int vec_record::*member) {
    for(auto &datum : data)
        std::cout << datum.*member << '\n'; // Accessing the member
}
```

Called like so :

```
change(data, &vec_record::term);
```

If applicable, you can also pass them by non-type template parameter :

```
template <unsigned int vec_record::*Tmember>
void change(vector<vec_record> &data) {
    for(auto &datum : data)
        std::cout << datum.*Tmember << '\n'; // Accessing the member
}
```

Called like so :

```
change<&vec_record::term>(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an AoS approach you might want to consider using SoA:

```
struct vec_record {
    vector<int> term;
    vector<int> coef;
};

vec_record data;
change(data.term);
change(data.coef);
```